# Android VideoView "Video cannot be played" works in Gallery

Tags: android, mp4, android-videoview

I receive an error when trying to play a large m4v file in my Android application.
"Sorry, this video cannot be played"
The VideoView's onError handler gets called like:
onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)

With "what" being 1 and "extra" being -2147483648

The exact same video plays without issues in the Gallery application.

Comment: is it a problem with only this clip or all the clips? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, android support mp4 but not m4v, asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552181/does-m4v-format-file-play-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

have you set the permission to read the internal storage???

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

do this and it should work